# Can I use bare imports for my local modules using native es6 modules (mjs)?

Tags: node.js, commonjs, es6-modules

## Background:

Assuming my folder structure is something like:

```
  project/
   -- package.json
   -- index.mjs
   -- lib/
       -- config/
           -- index.mjs
```

When I used `require()` natively in node I could reference a local module using a bare import like:

`const x = require('config')`

because I added the root of my library folder to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable. (assuming of course when I was using cjs/require the extension would have been `.js`)

## The problem:

When I try to do that using native es6 modules (mjs) like:

`import x from 'config'`

I get the error:

`Error [ERR_MODULE_RESOLUTION_LEGACY]: config not found by import in [SOME_ABS_PATH]/index.mjs. Legacy behavior in require() would have found it at [SOME_ABS_PATH]/lib/config/index.mjs`

## The question:

Anyone know how to solve this? Or what the future is for dealing with relative paths for local module resolution within the node native es6 module system?

## Research so far:

Only resource I've found on this so far is from here http://2ality.com/2017/09/native-esm-node.html stating:

> Path resolution works slightly differently: ESM does not support NODE_PATH and require.extensions. And its specifiers always being URLs also leads to a few minor differences.

And on the error message below `ERR_MODULE_RESOLUTION_LEGACY` - google showed up literally nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so a colleague (thanks @robin-balmforth ) gave me the answer:

From https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_node_path it says:

> Notable differences between import and require No NODE_PATH NODE_PATH
>   is not part of resolving import specifiers. Please use symlinks if
>   this behavior is desired.

And from something even more canonical:

https://github.com/bmeck/node-eps/blob/es6-module/002-es6-modules.md#521-removal-of-non-local-dependencies says:

> All of the following will not be supported by the import statement:
>
> $NODE_PATH $HOME/.node_modules $HOME/.node_libraries $PREFIX/lib/node
>   Use local dependencies, and symbolic links as needed.

So instead of me setting the NODE_PATH environment variable I have to setup a symlink like:

`ln -s ../lib node_modules/lib`

Seems to work fine yay.

We suppose the reason is for compatibility with the browser implementation of es6 modules?

There is *some* discussion on the reasoning behind this change from https://github.com/bmeck in this node-eps issue https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/issues/11 like:

> The solution is not a workaround, it is how path resolution works.
>   Having a single flat namespace for "bare" path resolution is
>   important.

Comment: Thank you! For those receiving "too many levels of symbolic links" when attempting to import from a local src directory when writing tests, this approach of creating a symbolic link to the module, combined with relative symlinks https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152088/296985, combined with a postinstall package.json hook, resolves the issue.